# Start a Thread Timer directly

Tags: python, timer

I want to trigger the `self._runSequence()` func directly after start the timer. This is my code:

```
self.sequenceTimer = RepeatedTimer( sequenceDuration, self.__runSequence, sequence)
```

If `sequenceDuration` is equal to `10` the func will be called 10 seconds later (as a normal timer I know..)

This is the `RepeatedTimer` `Class`:

```py
from threading import Timer
    
class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer     = None
    self.interval   = interval
    self.function   = function
    self.args       = args
    self.kwargs     = kwargs
    self.is_running = False
    self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
```

What I already try:

```
self.sequenceTimer = RepeatedTimer( sequenceDuration, self.__runSequence(sequence), sequence)
```

But this give me an error when the timer trigger the `__runSequence` func that tell me I don't give an argument to `__runSequence()` func.

Comment: What is the object for `self.sequenceTimer` and `self.__runSequence`?

Comment: `self.__runSequence()`is a func with some `time.sleep()`. So in need to call it with async method like thread. `self.sequenceTimer` Is the instance of `RepeatedTimer`, I need it to `stop()` the timer as I want.

Comment: I can't notice any problems with the `RepeatedTimer` class. It works fine for me (e.g. `RepeatedTimer(10, print, "foo", "bar", sep=";")`).

Comment: I think you need to check the other class (where `__runSequence` belongs to). Or post it here to help you.

Comment: @SvenEberth yes this code work well. But I need to call `print` not 10s later, but instantly when I initialise the `RepeatedTimer()`

Comment: It was a bit unclear and confusing, because you said _"directly after start the timer"_ (but you probably mean `RepeatedTimer` and not `threading.Timer`) and later told something about an argument error. but I think I understood it now, also your approach which caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the `function` to be executed when the `RepeatedTimer` is initialized, and then periodically, right?

Instead of calling `start` in `__init__`, call `_run`. It calls `start` and execute the `function`.

```
import time
from threading import Timer
    
class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer     = None
        self.interval   = interval
        self.function   = function
        self.args       = args
        self.kwargs     = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self._run()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False


print("Before initialization")
sequence_timer = RepeatedTimer(10, lambda *args, **kwargs: print(time.time(), *args, **kwargs), "foo", "bar", sep=" ; ")
print("After initialization")
time.sleep(50)
sequence_timer.stop()
```

Output

```
Before initialization
1622809236.0391436 ; foo ; bar
After initialization
1622809246.0429533 ; foo ; bar
1622809256.055273 ; foo ; bar
1622809266.0606596 ; foo ; bar
1622809276.0665863 ; foo ; bar
```

You can see that the first execution occurs before the initialization is complete.

---

Your first attempt was already correct.

```py
self.sequenceTimer = RepeatedTimer(sequenceDuration, self.__runSequence, sequence)
```

The second would pass the result of `self.__runSequence(sequence)` (`None` unless you explicitly return something else) instead of the method itself.